# Woocommerce set sale price to regular price - 15% discount

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a lot of products (nearly 30,000) in woocommerce.
The regular price has been set properly, now I want to set the sale price to the regular one with some percentage of discount.
I tried with some plugin but I had always a PHP memory error due to the numbers of products.
So I'm trying to solve the problem directly in MYSQL.

Here is my SQL code:

`UPDATE s
SET s.meta_value = r.meta_value * 0.85,
FROM wp_postmeta s
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta r
ON s.post_id = r.post_id
WHERE s.meta_key = '_sale_price'
AND r.meta_key = '_regular_price'`

But there is an error in SQL syntax.
Please suggest to me how to correct the code.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer - after a lot of digging:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta AS s
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS r
ON s.post_id = r.post_id
SET s.meta_value = r.meta_value * 85 / 100
WHERE s.meta_key = '_sale_price'
AND r.meta_key = '_regular_price'
```

Everything is ok in DB but now the problem is I can't see the modification on product pages. Only if I enter the product in the admin and then save from there the sale price is refreshed in the product page. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

[Alessandro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5130706/alessandro), it's actually working. But you're at a half way to success:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta AS s
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS r
ON s.post_id = r.post_id
SET s.meta_value = r.meta_value
WHERE s.meta_key = '_sale_price'
AND r.meta_key = '_regular_price'

UPDATE wp_postmeta AS s
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS r
ON s.post_id = r.post_id
SET s.meta_value = r.meta_value
WHERE s.meta_key = '_price'
AND r.meta_key = '_sale_price'
```

That way you have sale price and the "current" price updated.
You'll have to **run both these scripts separately** when adding any new product.
AND **don't forget to clear the cache** with any caching plugin such as W3 Total Cache or similar.

p.s.: Good if future Woocommerce versions will include the feature to switch "current" price to _sale or _regular.

Comment: Just for reference, to reverse this (remove all discounts) use `UPDATE wp_postmeta AS s
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS r
ON s.post_id = r.post_id
SET s.meta_value = r.meta_value
WHERE s.meta_key = '_price'
AND r.meta_key = '_regular_price';` then 
`DELETE FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE meta_key = '_sale_price';`

Answer (score 0):

You could just permanently filter the sale price via the `woocommerce_get_sale_price` filter.

```
function so_31493236_sale_price( $sale_price, $product ) {
    $sale_price = $product->get_regular_price() * 0.15;
    return $sale_price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_sale_price', 'so_31493236_sale_price', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I need to set the value in the DB because in the future I will change some of this values to something else.